# Error in mgcv R package, depending of the R version

Tags: r

The following program works perfectly with R\2.15.3 with the mgcv packages:

```
foo<-c(0.08901294, 0.04221170, 0.01608613, 0.04389676, 0.04102295, 0.03552413, 0.06571099, 0.11004966, 0.08380553, 0.09181121, 0.07422538,
        0.11494897, 0.18523257, 0.13809043, 0.13569868, 0.13433534, 0.16056145, 0.15559133, 0.22381149, 0.13998797, 0.02831030)
infant.gamfit<-gam(foo~s(c(1:21)), family=gaussian(link = "logit"))
```

But with R\3.1.1 and 3.1.2, it produces the following error:

> Error in reformulate(pav) :   'termlabels' must be a character vector
>   of length at least one

Which is an error I don't understand.
Of course the values in foo is an example among others, but I have the same problem with other values. Fixing k in the spline doesn't change anything.

That wouldn't be a problem if I wouldn't need to use it on a large scale with a supercomputer where all the versions of R create the same error...
(for the sake of the discussion, the R versions I tested on the supercomputer were:

- R/2.15.3-foss-2014a-default;
- R/2.15.3-foss-2014a-st;
- R/2.15.3-intel-2014a-default;
- R/3.0.2-foss-2014a-default)

So that's not a supercomputer problem, but more a problem related to the use of mgcv in different version of R.

I didn't find any answer on the internet.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Guillaume

Comment: Relevant source: https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/models.R, Ctrl+F "reformulate" (may be helpful for diagnosing the issue)

Comment: Seems like it has nothing to do with R version (I see no diff in 2.15.3 and latest on the R side), so the main suspect is `mgcv`, please find out and post its' versions as suggested.

Comment: @RHertel mgcv is one of the packages that comes with base R.

Comment: @tonytonov  I used mgcv 1.8-4 with R\3.1.1. and 1.7-22 with R\2.15.3, so, yes it could come from the mgcv package. However, Hong Ooi was right and solved my problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like recent versions of `mgcv::gam` can be a bit fragile when your predictor is an expression, as opposed to a named variable. This works:

```
x <- 1:21
gam(foo~s(x), family=gaussian(link = "logit"))
```

As does this:

```
x <- 1:21
gam(foo~s(x + 0), ...)
```

But this doesn't:

```
x <- rep(0, 21)
gam(foo~s(x + 1:21), ...)
```

In general, I'd suggest you should precompute your predictors when using `gam`.

PS. Gaussian family with logit link isn't very sensible, but that's another issue.